# Reemplazar string en columnas, según palabras en listado

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente consulta que hacer:

Tengo una columna con texto asociado a reseñas. Dentro de estas reseñas, existen palabras que pueden ser consideradas ofensivas, las cuales tengo anotadas en un listado.

`listado=['palabra_ofensiva1','palabra_ofensiva2','palabra_ofensiva3']`

Lo que tengo pensado hacer es que, en caso de que una de las palabras que componen las reseñas está dentro del listado, la reemplace con asteríscos

En internet encontré el siguiente código para realizar lo último mencionado:

```
def censurador(texto, palabra):
    word_lenght = len(palabra)
    word_censorer = "*" * word_lenght
    lst_text = texto.split()
    censored_text = ""
    while palabra in lst_text:
        word_index = (lst_text.index(palabra))
        lst_text.remove(palabra)
        lst_text.insert(word_index, word_censorer)
    return " ".join(lst_text)
```

Entonces, traté de replicar esta función dentro de un if, para poder ir iterando segun cada palabra que componen las reseñas, pero acá es donde me sale un error:

```
for i in df['alerta_cdda_descripcion']:
    texto=i.split()
    for j in texto:
        word_lenght = len(j)
        word_censorer = "*" * word_lenght
        censored_text = ""
        while j in listado:
            word_index = (texto.index(j))
            texto.remove(j)
            texto.insert(word_index, word_censorer)
            " ".join(texto)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-d8349e3cb670> in <module>
      6         censored_text = ""
      7         while j in listado:
----> 8             word_index = (texto.index(j))
      9             texto.remove(j)
     10             texto.insert(word_index, word_censorer)

ValueError: 'palabra_ofensiva1' is not in list
```

Lo más probable, es que me haya equivocado en el último paso...

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar listas por comprensión:

```
palabras_ofensivas = ['palabra_ofensiva1','palabra_ofensiva2','palabra_ofensiva3']

df['alerta_cdda_descripcion'].apply(lambda x: [palabra for palabra in x if palabra not in palabras_ofensivas])
```